# Can I put a <select> function in a table via innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have been attempting to do.
It has not worked so far.
I don't know if this is possible but I hope someone can help.
I would be willing to take any advice going.

Thanks

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<b>" +  (i+1) + "</b>";


cell2.innerHTML = "<b>" + array1[j] + "</b>";
cell3.innerHTML = '<select id="hGls">
                      <option selected="">-</option>
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>';
cell4.innerHTML = <select id="aGls">
                      <option selected="">-</option>
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                      <option value="7">7</option>
                      <option value="8">8</option>
                      <option value="9">9</option>
                      <option value="10">10</option>
                      <option value="11">11</option>
                      <option value="12">12</option>
                      <option value="13">13</option>
                      <option value="14">14</option>
                      <option value="15">15</option>
                      <option value="16">16</option>
                      <option value="17">17</option>
                      <option value="18">18</option>
                      <option value="19">19</option>
                      <option value="20">20</option>
                  </select>;
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: You're missing the quotes in `cell4.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: What do you mean by "It has not worked so far"? Whats the error you are getting, what happens instead?

Comment: What are you attempting to do is not clear

Comment: Can you really have [multiline string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript) the way you do it?

Comment: Unexpected token <   is the error Im getting

Comment: Remove the line breaks or add a \ before the line break in HTML strings.

Answer (score 1):

Simple remove the line-breaks (or escape them) and wrap the the select for cell4 into quotes.

```
cell4.innerHTML = '<select id="aGls"><option selected="">-</option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option></select>';
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7uz1zz95/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiline strings in javascript, To fix this you need to escape the new line:

```
cell3.innerHTML = '<select id="hGls">\
                      <option selected="">-</option>\
                      <option value="0">0</option>\
                      <option value="1">1</option>\
                      <option value="2">2</option>\
                      <option value="3">3</option\
                      <option value="4">4</option>\
                      <option value="5">5</option>\
                  </select>';

cell4.innerHTML = '<select id="aGls">\
                      <option selected="">-</option>\
                      <option value="0">0</option>\
                      <option value="1">1</option>\
                      <option value="2">2</option>\
                      <option value="3">3</option>\
                      <option value="4">4</option>\
                      <option value="5">5</option>\
                      <option value="6">6</option>\
                      <option value="7">7</option>\
                      <option value="8">8</option>\
                      <option value="9">9</option>\
                      <option value="10">10</option>\
                      <option value="11">11</option>\
                      <option value="12">12</option>\
                      <option value="13">13</option>\
                      <option value="14">14</option>\
                      <option value="15">15</option>\
                      <option value="16">16</option>\
                      <option value="17">17</option>\
                      <option value="18">18</option>\
                      <option value="19">19</option>\
                      <option value="20">20</option>\
                  </select>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Via a function?

```
function addNumbersOpts(id, max) {
    var buff = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        buff.push('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');

    return '<select id="' + id + '">' + buff.join('\n') + '</select>';
}

cell3.innerHTML = addNumbersOpts('hGls', 5);
cell4.innerHTML = addNumbersOpts('aGls', 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're missing the quotes at `cell4.innerHTML =`
2. You should write your code with concatenations:

   ```
   cell3.innerHTML = '<select id="hGls">' +
                         '<option selected="">-</option>' +
                         '<option value="0">0</option>' +
                         ...
                     '</select>';
   ```

   This makes it much clearer.

   Altermativeley, you can use `\` to escape the line break or squeeze them into a single line (as recommended by the other answers), but using concatenation is much clearer and doesn't have a performance overhead due to browser optimisations.